# Facebook login in React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, reactjs, react-native

I am developing an app in React Native and I want to implement logging in with Facebook.

I have an API in Node.js where I handle the logic for users to log in, etc.

I use passport.js to let users log in with either Facebook or traditional Email.

I am opening an URL in my API with `SafariView` which is just a regular "WebView" directly in my app.

I have tried using the following code:

```
class FacebookButton extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Add event listener to handle OAuthLogin:// URLs
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);

    // Launched from an external URL
    Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
      if (url) {
        this.handleOpenURL({ url });
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
  }

  handleOpenURL({ url }) {
    // Extract stringified user string out of the URL
    const [, user_string] = url.match(/user=([^#]+)/);

    this.setState({
      // Decode the user string and parse it into JSON
      user: JSON.parse(decodeURI(user_string))
    });

    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      SafariView.dismiss();
    }
  }

  openURL(url) {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      SafariView.show({
        url: url,
        fromBottom: true,
      });
    } else {
      Linking.openURL(url);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.openURL('https://mywebsite.com/api/auth/facebook')}
        title='Continue with Facebook'
        ...
```

so I guess I will have to do the authentication on URL `https://mywebsite.com/api/auth/facebook` and then send the user to an url that looks something like `OAuthLogin://...`, but I am not entirely sure how to use it.

Can anyone help me move in the right direction?

Comment: i would use the official sdk for this, it works fine: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/login

Comment: But I need the login to synchronise with the users already registered on the website, so I guess I will have to make it go through the API?

Comment: not sure what you mean, you get the user id after login and you can check if the user is already registered. same as with building a custom solution.

Comment: first, pass through authorization via sdk on the client and get the token then pass token to the server and find out user social id by token (u should store it) and if it exists - authorize him

Answer (score 0):

```
import { LoginManager, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk'; // add this file using npm i react-native-fbsdk
```

Create function

```
const onFacebookButtonPress = async () => {

// Attempt login with permissions
const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);

if (result.isCancelled) {
  throw 'User cancelled the login process';
}

// Once signed in, get the users AccesToken
const userInfo = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

if (!userInfo) {
  throw 'Something went wrong obtaining access token';
}
console.log('user info login', userInfo)
// Create a Firebase credential with the AccessToken
const facebookCredential = auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(userInfo.accessToken);
setGoogleToken(userInfo.accessToken)

// Sign-in the user with the credential
return auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
.then(() => {
    //Once the user creation has happened successfully, we can add the currentUser into firestore
    //with the appropriate details.
    console.log('current User @@@@', auth().currentUser);

    var name = auth().currentUser.displayName
    var mSplit = name.split(' ');
    console.log("mSplit ",mSplit);

    let mUserDataFacebook = {
        user_registration_email: auth().currentUser.email,
        user_registration_first_name: mSplit[0],
        user_registration_last_name: mSplit[1],
        registration_type: 'facebook',
        user_registration_role: "Transporter",
        token: userInfo.accessToken,
        user_image : auth().currentUser.photoURL,
        
    };
    console.log('mUserDataFacebook',mUserDataFacebook)
    LoginWithGoogleFacebook(mUserDataFacebook) /// Call here your API 
      
    firestore().collection('users').doc(auth().currentUser.uid) //// here you can add facebook login details to your firebase authentication.
    .set({
        fname: mSplit[0],
        lname: mSplit[1],
        email: auth().currentUser.email,
        createdAt: firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
        userImg: auth().currentUser.photoURL,
    })
    //ensure we catch any errors at this stage to advise us if something does go wrong
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Something went wrong with added user to firestore: ', error);
    })
  })
 
}
```

Call this function on button press onFacebookButtonPress()

For android need to setup and add facebook id in
android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml file
add these two lines.

YOUR_FACEBOOK_ID
fbYOUR_FACEBOOK_ID //Don't remove fb in this string value

/////////////add this code in AndroidMainfest.xml file

//////////This code add in MainApplication.java file

import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;

import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;

/////////add code build.gradle file

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'